# SQLite: How would you rephrase the query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I created a basic movie database and for that I'm working with SQLite.

I have a table, which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE movie_collection ( 
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, movie_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie (id) 
)
```

As one simple task, I want to show one user (let's say user_id = 1) the **whole movie collections**, in which the actual user(user_id = 1) might or might not have some movie collection. I also have to prevent the multiple result sets, where more than one user have the same movie record in their collection, especially if this involves the actual user (user_id = 1) then **he has the priority**, that is if there are let's say 3 records as following:

```
user_id   movie_id
--------  ---------
  1          17
  5          17
  8          17
```

Then the result set must have the record (1, 17) and not other two.

For this task I wrote a sql query like this:

```
SELECT movie_collect.user_id, movie_collect.movie_id
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, movie_id FROM movie_collection WHERE user_id = 1
    UNION
    SELECT user_id, movie_id FROM movie_collection WHERE user_id != 1 AND movie_id NOT IN (SELECT movie_id FROM movie_collection WHERE user_id = 1)
) AS movie_collect
```

Altough this query delivers pretty much that what I need, but just out of curiosity I wanted to ask, if someone else has an another idea to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: `user_id  1` is not valid SQL.

Comment: @CL that's right. For the "not equal" I used "<>". But it's somehow ignored by the editor. I replaced it with "!="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer query is superfluous:

```
SELECT user_id, movie_id
FROM movie_collection
WHERE user_id = 1

UNION

SELECT user_id, movie_id
FROM movie_collection
WHERE user_id != 1
  AND movie_id NOT IN (SELECT movie_id
                       FROM movie_collection
                       WHERE user_id = 1)
```

And UNION removes duplicates, so you do not need to check for `uid` in the second subquery:

```
SELECT user_id, movie_id
FROM movie_collection
WHERE user_id = 1

UNION

SELECT user_id, movie_id
FROM movie_collection
WHERE movie_id NOT IN (SELECT movie_id
                       FROM movie_collection
                       WHERE user_id = 1)
```

And the only difference between the two subqueries is the WHERE clause, so you can combine them:

```
SELECT user_id, movie_id
FROM movie_collection
WHERE user_id = 1
   OR movie_id NOT IN (SELECT movie_id
                       FROM movie_collection
                       WHERE user_id = 1);
```

Comment: It looks fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: There is an issue with the last query you wrote though. If the user (user_id = 1) doesn't have a movie record (e.g. movie_id  = 5) but if there are more than  one other users who have this movie (movie_id = 5) in their collection, then the query returns records with duplicate movie id's. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: OK. So, I didn't specify it in my question that the query should fulfill this condition, neither my own query returns records with distinct movie_id. But I really like to have records which include distinct movie id's. :-D

Comment: I think, I just solved the problem. With adding `GROUP BY movie_id` to the end of the query, which reduces the records that include different user_ids and duplicate movie ids. Since it's not important from which user the record should be shown/taken, `GROUP BY` works well. :-D